# Not printing entire text file from bufferedreader

Tags: java, swing, text-files, bufferedreader

The goal of this project is to be able to see how popular a baby name was for a given year from 2006-2010.  I am attempting to use a buffered reader (My first time using one) to read the file.  Depending on what year they select the file may change.  I need to go through the file line by line, and then display in the GUI what rank the name had for that year.

For the time being I am simply having the entire contents of the file printed in the Java console to make sure that it is reading the entire file.  The problem I am having is that it only prints from line 955 to 1000(end of file), skipping the first 944 lines in the text document.  This occurs no matter which file I tell it to open.  I am also unsure how to use a buffered reader to check each line for the specific string, in this case, the variable "name".

```
class ClickListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Parse Input Fields
        String name = inputArea.getText();
        String genderSelected = genderList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String yearSelected = yearList.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String yearFile = "Babynamesranking"+yearSelected+".txt";            

        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File(yearFile);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of File: ");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of input files:

```
941     Darryl  211     Yamileth    273
942     Jakobe  211     Emmy    272
943     Koen    211     Averi   271
944     Darien  210     Mylee   271
945     Haiden  210     Kylah   270
946     Legend  210     Anabel  269
947     Tyrese  209     Thalia  269
948     Zaid    209     Carina  268
949     Dangelo 208     Esperanza   268
950     Maxx    208     Jamya   268
951     Pierre  208     Kierra  268
952     Camdyn  207     Sydnee  268
953     Chaim   207     Audriana    267
954     Damari  207     Shania  267
955     Sonny   207     Ivana   266
956     Antony  206     Micaela     266
957     Blaise  206     Kinsey  265
958     Cain    206     Azariah     264
959     Pranav  206     Kai     264
960     Roderick    206     Precious    264
961     Yadiel  206     Kimber  263
962     Eliot   205     Mina    263
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. How do you run it? Most likely the console only keeps the most recent 45 lines of output.

Comment: Ah, you're just running out of console lines, that's all. It's reading all the lines, and printing them, but the older lines are scrolling of the console's buffer.

Comment: Oh wow,  Well that makes me feel relieved.  I was really stressed as to why it wasn't accessing the whole file.  You're right though.  I added a call to the indexOf for the stringBuffer and it is finding the indexes of names from higher up the list